# Removing a variable pattern from the title of my files

Tags: command-line, bash, batch-rename

As I finally received data from NGS sequencing, for some days I used Ubuntu to analyse them. However, I lack the basics of shell coding, and I feel overwhelmed by this whole new language.

I managed to follow pipelines, but there are still beginner issues.

Specifically, I have a folder with 96 files that I want to rename. They are typically of the form:

```
AD18_S1_R2_cat_trimmed.fastq.gz
AD19_S26_R2_cat_trimmed.fastq.gz
```

Basically, I am trying to delete the sample ID, for instance `_S1` and `_S26`.
I recently discovered asterisks, and used them successfully for a previous function. But I have an issue imagining how to use them here.
What I think would work is to extract the expression between `_S` and `_R` and remove it, while keeping the `R`.

If the sample ID always had the same length, I would have used `[5-7]` to remove the characters from the name. But it won't work for some samples.

I want to understand how to do this, more than having the answer. Thus, would you kindly explain me how to make this change, and what does your code mean if you agree to share a solution?

Comment: Find patterns in filenames can be done with either wildcards or regular expressions. In this case, I believe wildcards will be the easiest solution. See [this article](https://linuxhint.com/bash_wildcard_tutorial/) for more info.

Comment: In your case, you would need to identify the filenames (I believe the expression `find AD*_S*_R*_cat_trimmed.*` will do. Then you need to split the filename (for instance using cut with `_` as the delimiter. And then you assign a new filename for each file, using the parts you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) The find function worked, and the asterisk indeed allowed to identify all the sample with both R1 and R2. I will now try and use the cut function to modify the titles.

Comment: This question is 100% on topic and very welcome here, but based on your file names, I suspect you might also be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mmv` is a nice tool for this. It is not installed by default, so you can install it using:

```
sudo apt install mmv
```

Then just run the following command in the directory where you keep the files:

```
mmv -n '*_*_R2_cat_trimmed.fastq.gz' '#1_R2_cat_trimmed.fastq.gz'
```

A simplified explanation:

- `-n` (no-execute) is used so that you get a preview of the changes without them getting applied. If you are satisfied with the output, rerun the command without the `-n` flag.
- You want to remove anything you have between the first and the second `_`, so the first argument of `mmv` (`'*_*_R2_cat_trimmed.fastq.gz'`) is a general expression for your files.

  The star is a wildcard that means "match any string of characters". So we match any string up to the first `_`, then any string between the first and second `_`, and we leave the rest of the file name as is.
- The second argument (`'#1_R2_cat_trimmed.fastq.gz'`) basically says "rename using the first match" (`#1`) and the rest is just the part of the string that we leave as is. Since we didn't use the second match (`#2`), we effectively removed it.

By default, `mmv` applies the changes in the background. If you want to see the changes while being made, you can use the `-v` (verbose) flag.

For more info about `mmv`, you can consult its manpage, by running [`man mmv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/mmv.1.html) in your terminal.

**Note:** Before running any command, always test it in a portion of your files to make sure that it works as you want and you don't lose any files. It's also good to always keep a backup of the original files.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I prefere your solution, it is easier to understand compared to pLumo's. This mmv function seems very useful. Thanks for the insights ! And yes, I already saved copies, and am practicing on some samples.

Answer (score 4):

Use `rename`:

```
rename -n 's/^([^_]*)_S[^_]*(_.*)$/$1$2/' *.fastq.gz
```

Remove the `-n` if you're happy with the output.

perl `rename` tool uses perl regular expressions similar to `sed`:

- `s/pattern/replacement/modifier` will search for pattern and replace it with replacement.
- `pattern` is a regular expression to match your string.
- `^([^_]*)_` => Search from beginning of the filename (`^`) anything up to the first `_` (`[^_]*`) and save it as variable `(...)` to be used in the replacement (`$1`).
- `S[^_]*` => Match an `S` followed by anything that is not an `_`.
- `(_.*)$` Match an `_` followed by anything (`.*`) (save a again as variable `$2`) until the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: Hello, first you have my thanks for the detailed explaination. 
When I saw all those characters in the code, I was scared. I still am, but now that everything is explained I shall understand how it is done.
I didn't know the -n command argument, I love it !
It worked. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

In general, when working with regular expressions, "less is more". I mean, avoid trying to match the entire string, instead focus on matching just the bit you are insterested in. In this case, the letter `S` followed by one or more numbers. That can be expressed in Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) syntax, the syntax used by the `rename` tool, as `S\d+`.

With this in mind, here's a simpler `rename` command:

```
$ rename -n 's/_S\d+//' *fastq.gz
AD18_S1_R2_cat_trimmed.fastq.gz -> AD18_R2_cat_trimmed.fastq.gz
AD19_S26_R2_cat_trimmed.fastq.gz -> AD19_R2_cat_trimmed.fastq.gz
```

That command will replace the first instance of a `_` followed by `S` and then one or more numbers (`\d+`) with nothing, so effectively removing it. The `-n` tells `rename` not to rename anything but only to print what it would do. Once you've confirmed this does what you want, remove the `-n` to make the command actually rename the files.